# MVC, is it bad practise to not dispose of the Entities object so you can use it to drill down on foreign key values?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm new to MVC.
In the tutorials I've gone through they say it is good practise to have your entities object disposed of after it is passed to the view. Like so...

```
using(MyProjectEntities db = new MyProjectEntities)
{
    return View(db.PersonAddresses.ToList());
}
```

However I don't want to just display the IDs of the Person and the Address records that are linked in the PersonAddress table. I want the whole shebang and I get an error when I do the following in my view.

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <%: item.Person.LastName + ", " + item.Person.FirstName %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.Address.AddressLine1+ "<br />" + item.Address.AddressLine2 %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.Room.RoomName %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: String.Format("{0:g}", item.Date) %>
        </td>
    </tr>

<% } %>
```

However if do

```
MyProjectEntities db = new MyProjectEntities;
return View(db.PersonAddresses.ToList());
```

My view works fine.

Is there a better way of passing those values to the view where I can dispose of the Entities object properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to "eager" load the data by adding [.Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) in your LINQ query, this pre-loads the specified data so it is ready to go.

Comment: Wow, this is so awesome I had no idea I could do this!

Comment: Glad to shed some light on it for you, it's good to know when working with EF and lazy loading

Answer (score 0):

It's better not to access your data layer directly from your controllers. I would create a separate business logic layer or service layer, and call that from the controllers, instead of calling the data access layer from your controllers. So your data access layer is not directly accessed by your user interface layer. This issue would then be moot.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Shan! My skills are not quite ready to take that step just yet. I'm trying to master the basics of setting up common controls such as dropdownlists and calendars before I start using a true business layer.